# How can I better optimize a search in possible Fantasyland constructions in Pineapple poker?

Tags: search, mathematical-optimization, heuristics, poker, simulated-annealing

So, a bit of explanation to preface the question. In variants of Open Face Chinese poker, you are dealt one and one card, which are to be placed into three different rows, and the goal is to make each row increasingly better, and of course getting the best hands possible. A difference from normal poker is that the top row only contains three cards, so three of a kind is the best possible hand you can get there. In a variant of this called Pineapple, which is what I'm working on a bot for, you are dealt three and three cards after the initial 5, and you discard one of those three cards each round.

Now, there's a special rule called Fantasyland, which means that if you get a pair of queens or better in the top row, and still manage to get successively better hands in the middle and top row, your next round becomes a Fantasyland round. This is a round where are dealt 15 cards at the same time, and are free to construct the best three rows possible (rows of 3, 5, and 5 cards, and discarding 2 of them). Each row yields a certain number of points (royalties, as they're called) depending on which hand is constructed, and each successive row needs better and better hands to yield the same amount of points.

Trying to optimize solutions for this seemed like a natural starting point, and one of the most interesting parts as well, so I started working on it. My first attempt, which is also where I'm stuck, was to use Simulated Annealing to do local search optimization. The energy/evaluation function is the amount of points, and at first I tried a move/neighbor function of simply swapping two cards at random, having first places them as they were drawn. This worked decently, managing to get a mean of around 6 points per hand, which isn't bad, but I often noticed that I could spot better solutions by swapping more than one pair of cards at the same time. Thus, I changed the move/neighbor function to swapping several pairs of cards at once, and also tried swapping a random amount of pairs between 1 and 3 through 5, which managed to yield slightly better results, but still I often spot better solutions by simply taking a look.

If anyone is reading this and understands the problem, any idea on how to better optimize this search? Should I use a different move/neighbor function, different Annealing parameters, or perhaps a different local search method, or even some kind of non-local search? All ideas are welcome and deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated a performance requirement, so I'll assume that this should work quickly enough to be usable in a game with human players.  It can't take an hour to find the solution, but you don't need it in a millisecond, either.

I'm wondering of simulated annealing is the right method.  This might be an opportunity for brute force.

One can make a very fast algorithm for evaluating poker hands.  Consider an encoding of the cards where 13 bits encode the card value and 4 bits encode the suit.  OR together the cards in the hand and you can quickly identify pairs, triples, straights, and flushes.

At first glance, there would seem to be 15! (13,076,743,680,000) possible positions for all the cards which are dealt, but there are other symmetries and restrictions that reduce the meaningful combinations and limit the space that must be explored.

One important constraint is that the bottom row must have a higher score than the middle row and that the middle row must have a higher score than the top row.

There are 3003 sets of bottom cards, COMBINATIONS(15 cards, 5 at a time) = (15!)/(5!*(15-5)!) = 3003.  For each set of possible bottom cards, there are COMBINATIONS(10 cards, 5 at a time) = (10!)/(5!*(10-5!)) = 252 sets of middle cards.  The top row has COMBINATIONS(5 cards, 3 at a time) = (5!)/(3!*(5-3)!) = 10.  With no further optimization, a brute force approach would require evaluating 3003*252*10 = 7567560 positions.  I suspect that this can be evaluated within an acceptable response time.

A further optimization uses the constraint that each row must be worth less than the row below.  If the middle row is worth more than the bottom row, the top row can be ignored by pruning the tree at that point, which removes a factor of 10 for those cases.

Also, since the bottom row must be work more than the middle and top rows, there may be some minimum score the bottom row must achieve before it is worth trying middle rows.  Rejecting a bottom row prunes 2520 cases from the tree.

I understand that there is a way to use simulated annealing for estimating solutions for discrete problems.  My use of simulated annealing has been limited to continuous problems with edge constraints.  I don't have a good intuition for how to apply SA to discrete problems.  Many discrete problems lend themselves to an exhaustive search, provided the search space can be trimmed by exploiting symmetries and constraints in the particular problem.

I'd love to know the solution you choose and your results.

Comment: You're right, it might in fact be possible to brute force; the author of the library I'm using for hand evaluation states that he was able to evaluate ~250k hands per second, and since each of the ~7.5M positions contain three hands, it would in that case take a minute and a half. Being able to trim when the middle row is worth more than the bottom row is certainly beneficial. I'm going to try to implement a brute force search and report back.